If the suspension of $M$ is homotopy equivalent to a smooth manifold, does $M$ bound a contractible smooth manifold?
Let $M$ be a smooth $(n-1)$-manifold. If $M$ bounds a contractible $n$-manifold $C$, then the suspension of $M$ is homotopy equivalent to $$\partial (C\times I) = C\times (\partial I)\cup (\partial C)\times I = (M\times I) \cup C\times\{0,1\}$$ by contracting the two copies of $C$ on the "caps." The space $C\times I$ is a smooth manifold since $C$ is, hence the boundary is smooth, and thus the suspension of $M$ is homotopy equivalent to a smooth manifold.
Is the converse true? That is, if the suspension of (smooth) $M$ is homotopy equivalent to a smooth $n$-manifold, does $M$ necessarily bound a contractible smooth $n$-manifold?
It's clear that $M$ must be a homology sphere by Poincaré duality, but not every homology sphere smoothly bounds a contractible manifold; for example the Poincaré homology sphere does not bound a smooth contractible $4$-manifold, see this question.

A counter-example is given by any homology 3-sphere $Y$ which does not bound a smooth contractible 4-manifold, e.g. the Poincare homology sphere. The suspension of $Y$ is homotopy-equivalent to $S^4$.

Wow, is it? Why is that? Couldn't, for example, the higher homotopy groups vary?

for dimensions $\geq 5$ are you familiar with Kervaire-Milnor?

I am not! Do tell.

Here is a form of Whitehead's theorem that you can find, for instance, in Corollary 6.70 of
Davis, James F.; Kirk, Paul, Lecture notes in algebraic topology, Graduate Studies in Mathematics. 35. Providence, RI: AMS, American Mathematical Society. xvi, 367 p. (2001). ZBL1018.55001.

Suppose that $f: X\to Y$ is a continuous map of simply connected CW complexes which induces an isomorphism of all integral homology groups. Then $f$ is a homotopy-equivalence.

Now, take a 3-dimensional manifold $Y$ which is an integral homology 3-sphere. Let $X$ be the subspension of $Y$. Then $X$ is a simply connected homology 4-sphere. However, if $X$ is an $n$-dimensional simplicial complex which is a pseudo-manifold and a simply-connected $n$-dimensional homology sphere, then there exists a continuous map $f: X\to S^n$ inducing an isomorphism of homology groups: Just take any degree 1 map $X\to S^n$. (Pick an $n$-dimensional open simplex in $X$ and collapse its complement to a point.) Then, by the above version of Whitehead's theorem, $f$ is a homotopy-equivalence. It follows that the suspension of a 3-dimensional manifold which is a homology sphere is homotopy-equivalent to $S^4$.
However, as you correctly noted, a 3-dimensional homology sphere $Y$ need not bound a smooth contractible 4-manifold (e.g., if $Y$ is the Poincare homology sphere).  Thus, your question has negative answer.

Sorry for the ignorance, it seems like you are showing that any homology 4-sphere is homotopy equivalent to a 4-sphere. Why this does not apply to the homology 3-sphere you start with?

@AndreaMarino: Simply connected one! Please, read my answer more carefully.

Thanks, I will! On the other hand, if you want to be clearer, you can state at some point that a simply connected homology sphere is homotopy equivalent to a sphere, then proceed to prove it.
